# Logging events for reporting purposes

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, logging, reporting

Are there any design patterns or best practices around logging events for use in reporting and BI systems.

For example in a system which manages orders from a website, it would be beneficial if a customer support worker could type in an order number and see that it the order was placed  on a certain day, dispatched on a certain day and delivered on another.

I can see 2 ways around this. I have an order object which has the fields:

```
OrderDate
DespatchDate
DeliveryDate
```

and populate them if they have happend otherwise they will be null

OR

log some sort of events like which are messages like:

```
Order Number - "12312312" - Ordered on '2014/01/01'
Order Number - "12312312" - Despatched on '2014/01/01'
```

and add store the events in a database.

Are there any guidelines for this?
For example how does the work item history in TFS work?

[image: TFS History]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Robert made good points in his answer.

In addition, you might want to look at Audit Log as described by Martin Fowler [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/AuditLog.html) (and perhaps, more generally, [Temporal Patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/timeNarrative.html)). If you wanted to do more than just business activity monitoring / business reporting of these events, you might want to look at Event Sourcing. Fowler provides an introduction [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).

You can use these terms to search for other opinions on the web.

Comment: Audit Log is exactly the term I was looking for.

Comment: Martin Fowler seems to have deleted the content from that Audit Log article some time in 2014. Thankfully, web.archive.org has a copy of what [it looked like on 2014-04-13](https://web.archive.org/web/20140413205804/http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/AuditLog.html).

Answer (score 8):

If this is an actual business-related report that is going to be generated and given to someone, then generate event records into a database, and then create a report from those records.  Give the records actual semantic meaning, rather than merely attaching a message.  In other words, make them first-class citizens.

Logging serves a different purpose.  Logging is intended as a systems monitoring tool, not a business logic mechanism.  If the report is an integral part of running the business, then make it an integral part of the application.